# How to iterate over all instances of a class in Dymola?

Tags: for-loop, modelica, dymola

I am currently simulating a district heating network model which contains a lot of pipes in Dymola and wish to calculate some data regarding the whole network i.e total heat loss in the pipeline.

The obvious way to do this is to iterate over every pipe using a for loop and sum the individual heat losses. I am however unsure how I can iterate over every pipe. Each pipe in the network is an instance of a class I created "Pipe" declared as follows:

```
 replaceable model Pipe =
      DHNAEE.Components.Pipe.PipeHeatLossMod_Double;
```

and each pipe then being defined as an instance of the Pipe class like below:

```
 Pipe dualPipeK30_c78(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter=0.02, thicknessIns=0.036, length=12.3, m_flow_nominal=5,nPorts = 1)
```

My question is, is there a way I can simply iterate over all instances of class "Pipe" in the model and sum a particular output i.e the heat loss from each? I am currently doing this in Python during post-processing but to directly have this from Dymola would be much more beneficial.

Many Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 3):

If all pipes use that special class that you have control over and it is a dynamic physical property you could in your Pipe-class add something like (not tested):

```
   outer MyHeatCapacitor heatSink;
   model MyHeatCapacitor
     extends Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.HeatCapacitor;
     annotation(missingInnerMessage="Need to add global heatSink");
   end MyHeatCapacitor;
equation
   connect(..., heatSink.port);
```

And the global heat-losses will then be collected in that heatSink component(automatically added).

Another option (especially when you cannot modify the Pipe-class) might be possible in the future: 
http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/118/026/ecp15118245.pdf
https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/browser/MCP/public/MCP-0021_ComponentIterators